# Velocity.js. Reset {bottom, top} to "auto" doesn't work and it remains "0px"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, velocity.js

I'm using Velocity in [this way](http://jsbin.com/buzige/1/edit?html,output).

I need Velocity reset the top:"0px" to "auto", but id doesn't work.

It's a bug? Or it's me?

It is the right way to do this animation or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animating to `auto` is simply not supported in Velocity.
There are many ways to tackle this, a simple one would be to store the initial `top` position and then reuse it like here: http://jsbin.com/wudepalude/2/

Comment: If I resize the page, the bottom is set different. How to fix?

Comment: And another way to do this? Not with store of variable top?

Comment: Another way would be to to re-calculate `$('div.square').offset().top` on every click. You could also update that value in an event handler on `window.resize` event but you'll have to debounce that handler.

Comment: And a solution without the css "top" tag?

Comment: Instead of `top` you can animate `bottom` between 0 and `container.height - square.height`. If you open a more specific fiddle I can help you on that.

Comment: What you mean with "a more specific fiddle"? You can't use this one? http://jsbin.com/buzige/1/edit?html,output